# PHP remove JSON objects with OR condition

Tags: php, json

I have to following problem to solve:

This is my JSON:

```
{
    "colors": [{
            "color": "red",
            "value": "#f00"
        },
        {
            "color": "green",
            "value": "#0f0"
        },
        {
            "color": "blue",
            "value": "#00f"
        },
        {
            "color": "magenta",
            "value": "#0ff"
        },
        {
            "color": "magenta",
            "value": "#f0f"
        },
        {
            "color": "black",
            "value": "#ff0"
        },
        {
            "color": "black",
            "value": "#000"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I have to receive all the objects where "color" is "magenta" and "black" and remove all the other objects. I only need objects containing "magenta" and "black".

I already tried this one:

```
$my_var = json_decode($json, true);
unset($my_var["magenta"]);
$json = json_encode($my_var);
```

But this can only remove one value, I need just the specified ones and none more.

The values for "magenta" and "black" are variable so they can differ in my application and can also be "blue" and "brown"
Can anyone help?

Comment: you have to loop through it.

Comment: use [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a starting point. You can pass in an array of invalid colours.

```
$my_var = json_decode($json, true);

$validColours = array('black', 'magenta');

$my_var['colors'] = array_filter (
    $my_var['colors'],
    function($v) use ($validColours) {
        return in_array($v['color'], $validColours);
});

$json = json_encode($my_var);
```

Comment: This one worked for me. I just had to remove the ! before in_array to get the invalid objects. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, sorry yeah my bad. I misread it and thought you wanted to remove those ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
$my_var = json_decode($js,true);

$result = array_filter($my_var['colors'], function($v){ return $v['color'] == "magenta" || $v['color'] == 'black';});
```

and replace "magenta" and "black" with colors you need, or assign values to some variables and use variables to compare.